# HTML5 player not working in multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mediaelement.js

I have an HTML5 audio player that works fine in Chrome...
http://66.147.244.101/~fastlif2/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/mp3player.html
... but does not work in IE or FireFox.

I have an alternative FLASH player that should play when the user can't view the mp3 using the audio tag. But it isn't showing up. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just convert the mp3 file into an ogg format and remove the flash player?

Comment: what happens then, do you get an area where the flash box should appear but on right click get the "movie not loaded"?

Answer (score 0):

1. For Flash fallback, you sometimes have to provide a path to the fallback SWF player in a JS call. Usually this is done in the init call for the video player. Are your paths correct?
2. If you're writing the video tags dynamically into the page, you'll need a shim for IE8.
3. If you're initializing your video player via javascript, make sure you wrap it in a $(document).ready(); or somesuch to make sure all your scripts are in the page before you init.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) a look. It's a library that will get you started with cross-browser HTML5 video that also supplies fall backs for browsers without support